# Best way to do MVC project working with POS device and Members gain points system

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Hello as the title say I'm gonna start a new project contains Members and they gain points when they spend with their credit card and the card that I will give to them which is created by my system. So I will need API which will get information from POS device. when I recieve I should get the member ID money that member spend and I will calculate the points he will get. So what is the best way to do this ? web services or API. I will use asp .net mvc but never done this kind of project that works with POS and maybe more devices in the future. SHould I use controller for calculating and recieving member from POS or controller-webservice. Could you lead me to create the logic of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use web api 2, maybe HMAC to secure the data/ authenticity of the connection. Post the transaction data (member I'd, cash value and anything else) as json from the pos device to an action on the api controller. Log the transaction data in a database or some kind of persistent storage, you could even use blob storage if you so desired. Calculate the points and return this data from the action. You would more than likely want to store the members total points as well. This is the logic flow for what you have asked. Simple, a days work!

Comment: thx a lot. I will follow this. and 1 more question if you dont mind.  Should I calculate points and etc in api controller or api controller should just get information about customer and pass it to regular controller. is it more secure ?

Comment: What do you mean regular controller? Do you mean an MVC Controller? Calculate your points in the api controller or if you want abstract all of your logic into another class/library.

Comment: yes mevc controller. I am looking for the best secure way is it possible to send ID and etc from anyother place whitout permission so someone can try to get multiple points ?

Comment: You wouldn't use an MVC controller in that way. Api and Mvc Controller are equally secure. The HMAC I mentioned is how you secure it. You're going to have to do a lot of reading for this project and a lot of googling.

Comment: Yes gonna start with.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api and gonna check all resources that I can find in this way with the detail you gave me and thx a lot